# How to modify heightHint of a GridData

Tags: java, swt, grid-layout

I have a `Composite` with a `GridLayout` of one column.
Inside it, I put two `Canvas` *C1* and *C2*.
At the moment, I fix the `heightHint` of the *C1*'s `GridData` and `grabExcessVerticalSpace` of *C2*'s `GridData` is `true`.

Now, during the execution of the program, I would like to change *C1*'s height, I tried to modify its `GridData` `heightHint` but with no result. I also tried to change its `minimumHeight` but with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

During runtime if you modified the layout data you also need to call `Composite#layout()` on the parent of controls whose layout data was modified. In your case `layout()` of the parent composite of C1 and C2 must be called once the layout data is modified to cause the changes to take effect.